# .NET client library project sample code doesnt working

Tags: asp.net, blogger, blogspot

quotation from https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet
"A full working sample client, containing all the sample code shown in this document, is available in the .NET client library project. The sample is located at /trunk/clients/cs/samples/blogger/ConsoleSample.cs in the Source tab of the SVN repository.

Before compiling and running this sample, update the values of username, password, blogName, and postId with the appropriate values. The username and password values represent the credentials used to log in to Blogger. The blogName value is the start of your blog's blogspot URL.

The sample client performs several operations on the provided blog to demonstrate the use of the Blogger Data API.

To compile the examples in this document into your own code, you'll need the following using statements:

```
using Google.GData.Client;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

"
which part i change of code ?

Comment: Just follow the rest of the tutorial. The code posted is just some library loading stuff.